# Multiline search and replace with special characters in console

Tags: php, search, replace, batch-processing, multiline

I need to modify ~50 lines of code in 45 PHP files.
The code to be replaced in the files as well as the new code are the same in all PHP files but stand in different lines.
Thus I cannot use patch and since there are multiple lines containing characters like `", ', @, [, ]` etc. I failed to use sed as well as it interpreted the special characters as regular expressions etc. and just messed up my documents.
Is there some way I can do a batch replacement from the console without escaping my entire code block?
Specifically this:

```
        // BEGINN ENERGIEAUSWEIS
    $sql_energiepass="select * from openimmoDB.energieausweis where openimmo_obid='".$row["openimmo_obid"]."'";
    $result_energiepass= mysql_query($sql_energiepass);
    if (!$result_energiepass) {
        trigger_error("Konnte das Erzeugen des Energiepasses nicht ausfuehren!\n\r" .mysql_error()."\n\r".$sql_energiepass."\n\r");
    }
    else
    {
        $row_energiepass = mysql_fetch_array ( $result_energiepass );
    }
    $energiepass=$zustand_angaben->addChild('energiepass');
    $energiepass->addChild('epart', $row_energiepass["energieausweis"]);
    $energiepass->addChild('gueltig_bis', "");
    $energiepass->addChild('energieverbrauchkennwert', $row_energiepass["wert"]);
    $energiepass->addChild('mitwarmwasser', "");
    $energiepass->addChild('endenergiebedarf', $row_energiepass["wert"]);
    $energiepass_e1=$zustand_angaben->addChild('user_defined_simplefield', "");
    $energiepass_e1->addAttribute('feldname','epass_stromwert');
    $energiepass_e2=$zustand_angaben->addChild('user_defined_simplefield', "");
    $energiepass_e2->addAttribute('feldname','epass_waermewert');
    $energiepass_e3=$zustand_angaben->addChild('user_defined_simplefield', $row_energiepass["effizienzklasse"]);
    $energiepass_e3->addAttribute('feldname','epass_wertklasse');
    $energiepass_e4=$zustand_angaben->addChild('user_defined_simplefield', $row_energiepass["baujahr"]);
    $energiepass_e4->addAttribute('feldname','epass_baujahr');
    $energiepass_e5=$zustand_angaben->addChild('user_defined_simplefield', $row_energiepass["strom"]);
    $energiepass_e5->addAttribute('feldname','epass_stromwert');
    $energiepass_e6=$zustand_angaben->addChild('user_defined_simplefield', $row_energiepass["waerme"]);
    $energiepass_e6->addAttribute('feldname','epass_waermewert');
    // ENDE ENERGIEAUSWEIS
```

Should be changed to this:

```
    // BEGINN ENERGIEAUSWEIS
    $sql_energiepass="select * from openimmoDB.energieausweis where openimmo_obid='".$row["openimmo_obid"]."'";
    $result_energiepass= mysql_query($sql_energiepass);
    if (!$result_energiepass) {
        trigger_error("Konnte das Erzeugen des Energiepasses nicht ausfuehren!\n\r" .mysql_error()."\n\r".$sql_energiepass."\n\r");
    }
    else
    {
        $row_energiepass = mysql_fetch_array ( $result_energiepass );
    }
    $energiepass=$zustand_angaben->addChild('energiepass');
    $energiepass->addChild('epart', $row_energiepass["energieausweis"]);
    $energiepass->addChild('gueltig_bis', "");
    $energiepass->addChild('energieverbrauchkennwert', $row_energiepass["wert"]);
    $energiepass->addChild('mitwarmwasser', "");
    $energiepass->addChild('endenergiebedarf', $row_energiepass["wert"]);
    $energiepass_e3=$zustand_angaben->addChild('user_defined_simplefield', $row_energiepass["effizienzklasse"]);
    $energiepass_e3->addAttribute('feldname','epass_wertklasse');
    $energiepass_e4=$zustand_angaben->addChild('user_defined_simplefield', $row_energiepass["baujahr"]);
    $energiepass_e4->addAttribute('feldname','epass_baujahr');
    $energiepass_e5=$zustand_angaben->addChild('user_defined_simplefield', $row_energiepass["strom"]);
    $energiepass_e5->addAttribute('feldname','epass_stromwert');
    $energiepass_e6=$zustand_angaben->addChild('user_defined_simplefield', $row_energiepass["waerme"]);
    $energiepass_e6->addAttribute('feldname','epass_waermewert');
    $energiepass_e7=$zustand_angaben->addChild('user_defined_simplefield', $row_energiepass["enegietraeger"]);
    $energiepass_e7->addAttribute('feldname','homeinfo_epass_enegietraeger');
    // ENDE ENERGIEAUSWEIS
```

But the problem generally applies to any kind of multi-line code changes which may need to be done in all 45 PHP files (last time it was a different change that applied to 50 LOC, which I did by hand now as it was urgent).

Comment: This is a general question about how to implement multi line code changes across multiple files from the console in batch mode. I provided you with a current example, but I will have to do this several times in the future with different code blocks.

Comment: What is the target OS?

Comment: It's Linux - or, to be specific:
Linux srv 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux